# Reconstructing DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, artificial-intelligence, transform

At the moment I am processing data obtained from a simulator. This is put into a DataFrame from Pandas. Here the output is:

```
 1. DateTime, Sensor, Value
 2. 1/13/2021 12:56:10, XTDSX5, 16.55
 3. 1/13/2021 12:56:10, XTDSX6, 55.55
 4. 1/13/2021 12:56:10, XTDSX9p, -15.16
 5. 1/13/2021 12:56:20 PM, XTDSX5, 15.20
 6. 1/13/2021 12:56:20 PM, XTDSX9p, -15.66
 7. 1/13/2021 12:56:30 PM, XTDSX6, 55.56
etc.
```

Now I want to transform this data to:

```
 1. DateTime XTDSX5, XTDSX6, XTDSX9p
 2. 1/13/2021 12:56:10, 16.55, 55.55,-15.16
 3. 1/13/2021 12:56:20, 15.20, NaN, -15.66
 4. 1/13/2021 12:56:30, NaN, 55.56, NaN
```

This to make it fitting for an Artificial Intelligence Classification. Does somebody know how I can do this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(data=df,
                            index="DateTime",
                            columns="Sensor",
                            )
pivoted_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Basically, `pd.pivot_table` will create a new DataFrame, whose index will be the unique elements in `DateTime` column of original DataFrame `df`, and whose columns will be unique elements of `Sensor` column of original `df`.
There is no need to specify `value` argument of `pd.pivot_table`, since there is only another column in `df`.
Since a simple index is required by the answer, I then use `reset_index`, which preserves the `DateTime` index of `pivoted_df` as a column.

Comment: Hi, please add some comments that explain your answer.

Comment: @andrey.shedko I edited my answer.